# Where is the Sparkline tab in the Show group for Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, colors, formatting, microsoft-excel-2019

How would I display the high points?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ0tV.png)

Copilot says:

> You Apply Blue sparkline color and display the high points for the
> sparklines.
>
> Copilot Certainly! Let’s create sparklines in Excel, apply a blue
> color, and highlight the high points. Here are the steps:
>
> Create Sparklines: Select the cells where you want the sparklines to
> appear (for example, range G2:G4). On the Insert tab, in the
> Sparklines group, click Line. In the Data Range box, select the range
> B2:F4. Click OK. Show High Points: Select the sparklines. On the
> Sparkline tab, in the Show group, check High Point. To make the
> sparklines larger, adjust the row height and column width of the
> sparkline cells. Choose a nice visual style from the Style group.
> Change Sparkline Color: If you want to apply a blue color to the
> sparklines, follow these additional steps: Select the line sparklines.
> Go to the Sparkline tab. Click Marker Color and choose High Point.
> Select your desired blue color. Now your sparklines will display the
> high points in blue!
>
> Remember that sparklines are great for visualizing trends within a
> single cell, and customizing them allows you to highlight specific
> data points effectively123. Happy Excel-ing!

I'm just having trouble finding this "sparkline tab" in the "show group" to select highpoints.

I've looked at a [few sources](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/sparklines.html#:%7E:text=Customize%20Sparklines%201%201.%20Select%20the%20sparklines.%202,Sparkline%20tab%2C%20in%20the%20Group%20group%2C%20click%20Clear.).  Using Excel 2019.

Comment: Click on `Insert` Tab --> `Sparklines` Group --> `Lines`

Comment: that just gives me "data range" and "location range"

Comment: It will show as `Design` Tab I believe so and not `Sparklines`

Comment: yes.  My goodness.  Thanks.  Just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

From your `Screenshot` on top of the ribbon it shows:

[image]

---

**`Sparkline Tools --> Design`**.

---

For `MS365` it dedicatedly shows **`Sparkline`** when the lines are selected but for `Excel 2019` you need to click on the **`Sparkline Tools  --> Design`** Tab.